# React on user clicking already selected ListViewItem, MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ListView that looks like this, that controls which tab in my application that is opened.

```
<ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSubstanceName}" Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Substances}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Lägg till" Command="{Binding AddSubstanceCommand}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Ta bort" Command="{Binding RemoveSubstanceCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <WrapPanel>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
             </WrapPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I use the SelectedSubstanceName property to detect which tab to open, or switch to, if it's already open.

The property looks like this:

```
private SubstanceName selectedSubstanceName;
public SubstanceName SelectedSubstanceName
{
    get
    {
        return selectedSubstanceName;
    }
    set
    {
        selectedSubstanceName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSubstanceName");
        if (selectedSubstanceName != null)
        {
            if (!Tabs.Any(t => t.Identify(selectedSubstanceName.SubstanceNameID, typeof(SubstanceTabsViewModel))))
                AddTab(selectedSubstanceName);
            else
                SelectedTab = Tabs.First(t => t.Identify(selectedSubstanceName.SubstanceNameID, typeof(SubstanceTabsViewModel)));
        }
    }
}
```

The case I'm not able to cover is when the user clicks "someSubstance", the corresponding tab is opened, the user closes it, and "someSubstance" is still selected. If the user wants to open it again, he has to select some other substance (which will then be opened), and then click "someSubstance" again. Is it possible to trigger the property even when clicking the same ListViewItem?

I know I could add an event on double-click, but ideally, I want to avoid both events and double-clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that after clicking an item the first time the list's `SelectedItem` gets set. After clicking the same item the second time `SelectedItem` won't change because it is already set to that item. What you should do is set the `SelectedItem` to `null` after handling the click.

Answer (score 0):

Try to unselect all Items in your ListView after the tab is closed.

```
YOURLISTVIEW.UnselectAll();
```

So the next time someone selects an Item there will be a change.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually want to use the [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) class, but instead simply use the [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx), since it is the most basic way of representing a sequence of elements, but without the extras such as `SelectedItem`, `SelectedValue`, etc. that any class deriving from `Selector` has.

From there, it's merely a matter of *how* to represent each item in the `ItemsControl`. The behavior you want is to know when a specific item has been **clicked** on, which would make the [`Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button(v=vs.110).aspx) class a good candidate, since it handles click behavior through an `ICommand` interface. Obviously, since you know about `DataTemplate`s and styling in general, you should already know that you can customize how the button looks (visually) without sacrificing the actual behavior (click-handling).

---

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Substances}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <Button Style="{StaticResource SomeStyleToChangeItsLook}"
                     Command="{Binding Path=SelectSubstanceCommand}"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                     Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
       </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

public ICommand SelectSubstanceCommand { get; private set; }

private void SelectSubstance(object parameter)
{
    // Add the substance that was "clicked" on here however you want to do it.
}
```

---

Keep in mind I don't know what framework you are using, so I just gave a general example of how the Command code might look in your view-model. The key to MVVM and using WPFs awesome UI is to always think of what behavior you want and which controls offer that behavior. Ignore how they actually look because that can be changed without losing that behavior.